# Reduce the resolution of kinect v2 colorframe 1920*1080 to 640*480

Tags: colors, frame, kinect, resolution

I have done lot of search on internet to find the solution but failed. I was trying to reduce the resolution of **kinect v2 colorframe** but remains failed. If anyone have any idea how to solve this problem to reduce the resolution from **1920*1080 to 640*480.** I'll be very grateful. 
I also tried the following link [Kinect v2 for windows: resize color frame in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779835/kinect-v2-for-windows-resize-color-frame-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the effort. Nevertheless, I personally asked Microsoft this same question in Berlin 2014. They won't release a proper way of doing it. A post-acquisition reduction technique with 100% resolution reduction will also be tough to be achieved.

I tried using 3x3 kernel's to calculate the value of RGB points and then re-construct the image. It won't work perfectly but it might be a starting point.

Comment: hello I have successfully overcome by using applying a filter from the aforge.net library on Kinect ColorFrame or Bitmap, I tried It works for me. By the way thanks for the answering here

Comment: Can you update your answer then? I would also like to do it!